# XAudio2 voice pooling

Tags: audio, pool, voice, xaudio2

I seem to have some conflicting information, and I am not sure what is up to date and what is proper.

In this talk: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6871

They recommend pooling voices at the application level since there is a cost with destroying voices.

However, looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/xaudio2/nf-xaudio2-ixaudio2-createsourcevoice

It states:

> XAudio2 uses an internal memory pooler for voices with the same format. This means memory allocation for voices will occur less frequently as more voices are created and then destroyed. To minimize just-in-time allocations, a title can create the anticipated maximum number of voices needed up front, and then delete them as necessary. **Voices will then be reused from the XAudio2 pool**. The memory pool is tied to an XAudio2 engine instance.

So this leads me to believe I don't need pooling as XAudio2 has internal pooling. Then in another section:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/xaudio2/nf-xaudio2-ixaudio2voice-destroyvoice

> To avoid title thread interruptions from a blocking DestroyVoice call, the application can destroy voices on a separate non-critical thread, **or the application can use voice pooling strategies to reuse voices rather than destroying them**. Note that voices can only be reused with audio that has the same data format and the same number of channels the voice was created with. A voice can play audio data with different sample rates than that of the voice by calling IXAudio2SourceVoice::SetFrequencyRatio with an appropriate ratio parameter.

This has information on pooling again, which makes it seems like I should be pooling voices. Does anyone know of which information is correct? Should I be pooling voices or should I leave it to XAudio2's internal pooler?

Answer (score 0):

The docs are not inconsistent, but it's a bit subtle. If you just create voices with the same format, then internally they will get reused to help minimize the cost of creating/destroying voices.

You can, however, go further and directly reuse source voices at the application level. They have to use the same basic format (PCM vs. ADPCM, bitrate, and channel count), but they can be different sample rates.

See [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/tree/master/Audio) for example code for voice reuse.

> For games, you likely also want to prioritize voices and use 'voice stealing' to avoid having too many sounds playing at once which would be a muddle anyhow.

Comment: So I guess my question would be, is there any point to reuse source voices at the application level if internally they are reused (provided they are the same basic format)? Isn't that just extra code that is not needed?

Comment: As with all things performance: Try it with your workload and see if it matters. Most game audio engines use application level voice pooling FWIW.